# Firebase StreamBuilder errors

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Facing some errors that I can't seem to fix. I looked up updated docs that did not use the deprecated ones but still not working.
I included the errors and the respective errors and also bolded out the error words/sections. Ty

Errors:

1. The argument type 'List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [firechat] lib\screens\chat_screen.dart:90) = **children: messageWidgets,**
2. The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type. (body_might_complete_normally at [firechat] lib\screens\chat_screen.dart:77) = builder: (context, snapshot) **{**
3. The property 'docs' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. (unchecked_use_of_nullable_value at [firechat] lib\screens\chat_screen.dart:79) = final messages = snapshot.data.**docs**;

```
body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
              //this snap is diff than the query one above
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
                  List messageWidgets = [];
                  for (var message in messages) {
                    final messageText = message.data()['text'];
                    final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];

                    final messageWidget =
                        Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
                    messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
                  }
                  return Column(
                    children: messageWidgets,
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.